# Cannot Connect to HBase Server from Java Code

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I have installed Hadoop and Hbase on a VirtualBox VM running Ubuntu; both Hadoop and Hbase are running successfully in pseudo-distributed mode. I have disabled IPv6 on Ubuntu and changed the localhost to 127.0.0.1 in the hosts file on the VM.

I am trying to write some basic Java code on a Windows machine in Eclipse to connect to the Hbase instance, create a table, insert and retrieve data, etc. The code fails with an error that it cannot connect to the master. However, it makes the Zookeeper connection to the VM just fine.

On the Windows machine, I am able to connect to the Hbase instance info via the web browser via the same IP address and port that I specify in the Java code.

I have searched everywhere and tried everything that I could find, but it is still failing to connect to the master after it makes the zookeeper connection.

I have read that others have had this problem too, but no one has posted a solution.

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Could you please show me the error log?

Comment: Can you ping to VM from your host machine?

Comment: Hi -- Yes, I am able to ping the VM from the host machine. I am away from my machine now, so I will post the error logs when I return.

Answer (score 0):

The IP and Port used to view information are not the one used to read/write from/into HBase. To do so you need to use either the REST API (included in HBase) or Apache Thrift (2 thrift servers are included in HBase - thrift & thrift2)

I would recommend you to use Apache Thrift (thrift2)

To start REST use :

```
$HBASE-INSTALL-DIR/bin/hbase-deamon.sh start rest
```

To start Thrift use :

```
$HBASE-INSTALL-DIR/bin/hbase-deamon.sh start thrift
```

To start Thrift (v2) use :

```
$HBASE-INSTALL-DIR/bin/hbase-deamon.sh start thrift2
```

To use the Thrift client from Java for example you will need to [install thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) on the server and then generate the Java Classes using the hbase thrift file included with HBase.

By default Thrift will be listening on the **9090** port and REST on the **8080**

Usefull Links :

[HBase Thrift](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/ThriftApi)

[HBase REST](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Stargate)

Comment: Hi -- If I must use Thrift to read/write remotely to Hbase from my Java code, could you explain where the Java API enters the picture? Thanks!

Comment: Thrift is composed from three entities, the server, the client and thrift him self(this one is only used to generate the client), the server is already withing hbase and you start it using the command above, the client can be in many languages (in your case Java), this client is a set of classes you integrate in your project to connect to hbase and do your operations. to get those Java classes you need to download thrift, and use the `hbase.thrift` file (this is a configuration file describing what hbase can do) to generate those classes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok -- Someone gave me some 1-1 help that fixed the problem and I wanted to pass it along. It turned out to be an IP addressing issue with the VM and with my Windows machine. First, in the etc/hosts file on the VM, I had to take out '127.0.0.1 locahost' and instead insert '  localhost'. Second, on my Windows hosts file, I had to add ' '. Thankfully, that fixed the problem. Please let me know this is unclear since I have seen this problem posted quite a few times without suitable resolution. Also, since I am writing Java code to access the HBase instance in the VM, there was no need to use Thrift or REST -- the Java API was sufficient.